# Unable to build iOS ipa: Flutter expects a build configuration named Release or similar

Tags: ios, flutter

in my flutter app I have 3 Schemes, dev, stag and prod.
I also have 3 google plists as follow:
[image: Xcode plists]

whenever I try running flutter build ipa, im getting the following error:

```
The Xcode project defines build configurations: Debug-prod, Debug-uat, Debug-dev, Release-dev, Profile-dev, Profile-uat, Profile-prod, Release-uat, Release-prod
Flutter expects a build configuration named Release or similar.
Open Xcode to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
1. Click on "Runner" in the project navigator.
2. Ensure the Runner PROJECT is selected, not the Runner TARGET.
3. Click the Editor->Add Configuration->Duplicate "Release" Configuration.
```

I tried to create a release configuration, then I went into another issue

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json' (OS Error: No such
file or directory, errno = 2)".
```

knowing that I have 3 icons for each environment

[image]

same problem with Google list location:

```
Looking for GoogleService-Info.plist in /Users/alijaber/Desktop/PhazeRo/Saar-parent-github/saar_mobile_parent/ios/config/default/GoogleService-Info.plist
    No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory.
```

Any help would be grateful

Comment: Did you have any updates?

Comment: @JanneckLange yes, try to run the comment with the flavor, like flutter build ipa -- flavor dev